# How to do 'Summarizing' in Pig Latin?

Tags: sum, apache-pig, acl

Im trying to do a summarize operation with pig.

For example, I have a table called `t3`:

```
product price   country

A   5   Italy

B   4   USA

C   12  France

A   5   Italy

B   7   Russia
```

I need to do a summarize operation, using 2 keys: `product` and `country`.

1. I do concatenate operation, using `product` and `country`
2. I have to calculate the price, summarizing the price values just where `CONCAT` result repeats
3. Where `CONCAT` result does not repeat, price remains the same as in `t3` table.

The expected output could be:

```
CONCAT  Price_1
AItaly  10
BUSA    4
CFrance 12
BRussia 7
```

In pig i write following script (the code is wrong, but just to show an idea):

```
t3 = LOAD '/home/Desktop/3_table/3_table.data' AS (product:chararray, price:int, country:chararray);



c1 = FOREACH t3 GENERATE CONCAT(product, country);


c2 = FOREACH t3 GENERATE *, c1;

product_1 = GROUP c2 BY c1;
price_1 = FOREACH product_1 GENERATE group, SUM(product_1.price);

STORE price_1 INTO 'summarise_by_2_ID' USING PigStorage('\t');
```

Maybe someone can explain how to reach the expected result?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to calculate the sum per product and country you do not need to use the concat function. Just group by those two fields.

```
A = LOAD 's.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (product:chararray, price:int, country:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY (product, country);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE CONCAT(group.product,group.country), SUM(A.price);
```

Actually, the concat is not necessary here, it is only to format the output as expected.

```
DUMP C

(AItaly,10)
(BUSA,4)
(BRussia,7)
(CFrance,12)
```

Comment: Can i ask just one thing more?
If i need to 'classify' the same table. Expected result could be:
A (A, 5, Italy), (A, 5, Italy) 2
B (B, 4, USA), (B, 7, Russia) 2
C (C, 12, France)  1
The CODE:
t2 = LOAD '/home/Desktop/2_table/2_table.data' AS (product:chararray, price:int, country:chararray);
A = GROUP t2 BY product;
C = FOREACH A GENERATE group $1, COUNT($1);
STORE C INTO 'Classify' USING PigStorage('\t');

But i receive an error, pig does not like the diffinition $1. Is there any other way to define first element in: (A, 5, Italy), (A, 5, Italy), so i can count that A repeatc 2 times?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to do but something like this might help: `C = FOREACH A GENERATE group, $1, COUNT($1);`

Comment: returns: ``(A,{(A,5,Italy),(A,5,Italy)},2)
(B,{(B,4,USA),(B,7,Russia)},2)
(C,{(C,12,France)},1)``

Comment: Thanks, the idea is very similar! But is there any way to get the output joined to the original table, used in LOAD?